# Find line number where a substring is found in a large string in Perl

Tags: perl, line, substring

What is the best way to search for the line number for a substring in perl string? For e.x.:
Searching for "escape" in

```
"How to Format
► put returns between paragraphs
► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
► _italic_ or **bold**
► indent code by 4 spaces
► backtick escapes `like _so_`
► quote by placing > at start of line
► to make links
<http://foo.com>
[foo](http://foo.com)"
```

should give 6 as the line number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thought of another solution.  In sufficiently recent Perls, you can open a filehandle onto a string, and then just use the special `$.` variable to automatically keep track of the line number:

```
open my $handle, '<', \$str;
my $linenum;

while (<$handle>) {
    $linenum = $., last if /escape/;
}

close $handle;

if (defined $linenum) {
    print "Found match on line $linenum\n";
} else {
    print "No match found\n";
}
```

Comment: Don't use `$.`.  It's cryptic and global over all file handles.  Instead, `use IO::Handle;` and then say `$handle->input_line_number()`.

Comment: @mscha: Can IO::Handle be used on a scalar?

Comment: @Adam: definitely, as long as it is in fact an IO handle.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I would do it:

```
my $string = 'How to Format
- put returns between paragraphs
- for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
- _italic_ or **bold**
- indent code by 4 spaces
- backtick escapes `like _so_`
- quote by placing > at start of line
- to make links
<http://foo.com>
[foo](http://foo.com)';

if ($string =~ /escape/) {
  # Count the number of newlines before the match.
  # Add 1 to make the first line 1 instead of 0.
  my $line = 1 + substr($string, 0, $-[0]) =~ tr/\n//;

  print "found at line $line\n";
}
```

This avoids doing *any* work counting lines unless the string is actually found.  It uses the [`@-` variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@LAST_MATCH_START) to find out where the match started, and then uses [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) to count newlines.

Comment: Definitely more efficient, but the savings decreases as the size of the string and the position of the match increases.  Against the example string, it's nearly 5x faster, but against the entire text of War and Peace, it's barely 2x faster.  No, I don't know why I bothered to benchmark this.  Avoiding work on a Monday? :)

Answer (score 3):

`$.` This special variable will give you the input file line number, for more detail go to http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

```
use strict;
use IO::Handle;
my $search = 'escapes';
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
       if ($line =~ /$search/){
            my $line_number = DATA->input_line_number();
        }
}

__DATA__
"How to Format
? put returns between paragraphs
? for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
? _italic_ or **bold**
? indent code by 4 spaces
? backtick escapes `like _so_`
? quote by placing > at start of line
? to make links
<http://foo.com>
[foo](http://foo.com)"
```

Comment: Nice solution, but assumes the input text is (or can be) on a file handle

Comment: @Patrick, it's easy enough to open any scalar as a file handle in current versions of Perl.  A more serious limitation is that it doesn't work for a search pattern that may span multiple lines.

Comment: Don't use `$.`.  It's cryptic and global over all file handles.  Instead, `use IO::Handle;` and then say `DATA->input_line_number()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming that your input text is contained in a single scalar:

```
my $i = 0;
my $lineno;
for my $line (split(/\n/, $large_block_of_text)) {
 if($line =~ /escape/) {
  $lineno = $i;
  last;
 }
 $i++;
}

if(defined($lineno)) {
 print("'escape' is on line $lineno\n");
} else {
 print("'escape' was not found\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem by iteratively searching the string for both the target pattern and for newline characters:

```
my $str = "<your string above>";
my $linenum = 1;
my $found = 0;

while ($str =~ /(escape)|\n/g) {
    $found = 1, last if defined $1;
    ++$linenum;
}

pos($str) = 0;  # Reset last match position

if ($found) {
    print "Found match on line $linenum\n";
} else {
    print "No match found\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print a specific line from a file in Perl/CGI interface:

```
open(FILE,"<report_timing.log");
my @list = grep /\bslack\b/, <FILE>;
chomp @list;
print "$_\n<P>" foreach @list;
```